# Introductory book for Riemannian geometry

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, book-recommendation

Could you recommend some books for Riemannian geometry to me?

I am completely new to Riemannian geometry but have some very basic background for differential geometry, I want to know more about tangent space, tangent bundle, connection, tensor.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

A standard reference is [do Carmo](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0817634908). However, general tensors are not thorougly approached as far as I remember: he just mentions it *en passant*.

Another good reference, but that may not be appropriate since you are not acquainted with Riemannian Geometry, is [Helgason](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821828487). Differently from do Carmo, he treats tensors extensively.

Now, tangent bundle and tangent space are not objects exclusive to Riemannian Geometry. You can find good explanations about those objects in [Bredon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387979263), which is a remarkably excellent book and also in [Bröcker, Jänich](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521284708). One reference for this is also [Hirsch](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387901485), but Hirsch, as Helgason, may be too thorough for a first approach. Furthermore, Hirsch restricts himself to a specific definition of tangent vectors/tangent space which is useful, easily generalizable, intuitive but does not communicate very well with Riemannian Geometry, in which we like to visualize tangent vectors as derivations a lot of times. In that respect, the treatment of Bröcker, Jänich is very appropriate: he presents three definitions of tangent space.

I hope I was of some help.